# Entity Diagram does not detect Associations when Indexes were created before Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In Entity Framework, the entity diagram tool that uses "update model from database..." will fail to include associations (detected via foreign keys) if, when the database was created, the indexes were put on the foreign key columns before the foreign keys themselves were defined.

This is a known and resolved issue (https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/667), coming in the next release. But of course, I need to use this now.

Is there a known workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it, I created an new Association that matches exactly the existing one, directly from the .edmx visual interface.

The only thing missing, is that the .edmx does not know the actual Foreign Key in the database, yet behaves the same.

I don't know how you would do it for a batch though.